# Elastic search does not returns any results

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to use elastic search with MsSQL
but i cant find any results

the table name is Orders_Table
and the fields are [OrderID],[CustomerName],[UserFullName],[Status]

Step 1: build index

```
POST /_river/mytest_river/_meta
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": 
    {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://[my_ip];databaseName=mega",
        "user":"sa","password":"******",
        "sql":"SELECT [OrderID],[CustomerName],[UserFullName],[Status]  FROM [Orders_Table]",
        "poll":"5s",
        "index": "mega",
        "type": "orders_table"     
    }
}
```

the result

```
{
   "_index": "_river",
   "_type": "mytest_river",
   "_id": "_meta",
   "_version": 2,
   "created": false
}
```

Step 2: mappings

```
PUT /_river/_mappings/orders_table
{
    "orders_table" : {
        "properties" : {
            "OrderID" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "CustomerName" : {"type" : "string" },
            "UserFullName" : {"type" : "string" },
            "Status" : {"type" : "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

the result

```
{
   "acknowledged": true
}
```

step 3: _search

```
POST /_river/mytest_river/_search
{
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
           "query":    "7694964", 
           "fields": [ "OrderID" ]
        }
    } 
}
```

the results

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Why does row [OrderID]=**7694964** not found?

Why are the hits 0??

How can i bring the table results instead of the hits?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
POST /mega/orders_table/_search
{
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
           "query":    "7694964", 
           "fields": [ "OrderID" ]
        }
    },
    "size": 100
}
```

To get 100 documents or use [scan and scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scan-scroll.html) to get paginated results or even [from/size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html) to get the same. But, be careful with `size`, you don't want to set big values in there because it can bring your cluster down. The best would be, if you have many documents, to use scan and scroll.

Comment: no. still the same result.
{
   "took": 222,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}

Comment: it Worked!!
but how do i set the bulk size?.. i am not getting all the relevant rows.. as in the DB.

Comment: great.. another problem i have is with the polling.
I set it to every 5s but it seems not to be working.

Comment: To me this sounds like another question on Stackoverflow. The initial issue in this post has been answered.